# Currency update error when updating with currency converter api

Tags: magento2, php

When I try to update the currency rates with the import service Currency Converter API in Magento 2.3.0, I get an error as follows:

> Notice: Undefined index: USD_BRL in
>   vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency/Import/CurrencyConverterApi.php
>   on line 91

When I remove a currency which it throws the error for like above, it just shows the error for the next currency in line when I click import.

Line 91 in that file is as follows: `(double)$response[$currencyFrom . '_' . $to]`

It is the same as the one in the file on the Magento 2 GitHub.

I searched google for a couple of hours and nothing to this comes up?

Anyone experienced this before and has a solution?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it is an issue in Magento I think [this commit](https://github.com/Jitheesh/magento2/commit/fa1d2d2e2a20ae72162575e26976f12dd437e188) will solve the problem the issue link [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21487)